# Customize a webpart directly added to pagelayout

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, powershell

I have a page layout with embedded web parts. These web parts are not added in any web part zones. I want to edit properties of the web-part but when I edit the page I cannot see any way of doing it.

Any idea how could this be done, I am trying to find a way to get it done through power shell right now.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred approach would be to change them in the Page Layout, create a new solution package and deploy that to the farm. This avoids unghosting of the page layout file.

Or if you are clear about the consequences of unghosting you can go to the Master Page Gallery (`http://sitecollectionroot/_catalogs/masterpage`) and edit the Page Layout with SharePoint Designer or any other editing tool (upload/overwrite).

Note that your changes affect all existing and new pages that use of that page layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you're adamant in changing the webpart properties through powershell, you can use the following code:

```
//Get reference to the SPSite object
 $SPsite = Get-SPSite "http://mywebapp/sites/mySite"  

 //Iterate through all sub sites and root site  
 foreach($SPWeb in $SPsite.AllWebs){  

 //Get reference to the landing page. Since it is a publishing site so default.aspx is the landing page  
 $page = $SPWeb.GetFile("Pages/default.aspx")  

 //Checkout the page  
 $page.CheckOut()  

 //Get reference to the webpartmanager class  
 $webpartmanager = $SPWeb.GetLimitedWebPartManager("Pages/default.aspx",   
 [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)    


 //Iterate through webparts in webpartmanager class  
  for($i=0;$i -lt $webpartmanager.WebParts.Count;$i++)  {   

 //Check for the name of required web part   
  if($webpartmanager.WebParts[$i].title -eq "Relevant Articles")   
  {    

     //Get reference to the web part  
     $wp=$webpartmanager.WebParts[$i];  

     //Set the chrome property  
     $wp.ChromeType="TitleAndBorder";  

     //Save changes to webpartmanager. This step is necessary. Otherwise changes won't be reflected  
     $webpartmanager.SaveChanges($wp);  

     break;   

  }   
 }   

  //Check in and Publish the page  
  $page.CheckIn("Relevant Articles")  
  $page.Publish("Relevant Articles")  

  // Update the SPWeb object  
  $SPWeb.Update();   

  //Dispose SPWeb object  
  $SPWeb.Dispose();  
 }
```

Source: http://www.sharepoint-zone.com/2014/02/updating-web-part-properties-using.html

As mentioned, the easiest way to modify is by simply changing the page layout under the masterpage catalog folder.